# Django prefetch related objects from same model

Tags: python, django

How can I annotate each object in a queryset with related objects from the same model where one or more fields have the same value?

Basically I have an `Order` model and ideally I'd like to prefetch related orders where the `customer_email` field is matching.

I couldn't figure out how to do this so I tried to do annotate with a subquery and ArrayAgg to get the related order ids but I feel like it can be done with a prefetch? My attempt doesn't work because it returns more than one row.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer_email = models.EmailField()

from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

orders = (
    Order.objects
    .annotate(rel=Subquery(
        Order.objects
        .filter(customer_phone_number=OuterRef('customer_phone_number'))
        .order_by()
        .annotate(ids=ArrayAgg('id'))
        .values('ids')
    ))
)
```

I've also tried with `prefetch_related` but am getting an error.

> AttributeError: Cannot find 'self' on Order object, 'self' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

```
orders = (
    Order.objects
    .filter(date='2020-05-20')
    .prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'self',
        queryset=Order.objects.filter(customer_email=OuterRef('customer_email'))
    ))
)
```